How to run a file (e.g. VBScript) opened in Sublime Text?
I am learning VBS and making some scripts for practice. I find it inconvinient to switch to file explorer and run my VBScripts. Is there any way to execute files right from Sublime Text?

Have you installed this package? It adds syntax highlighting, but I don't know if it adds a Run option. VBSEdit is the really the gold standard for editing and debugging VBScript code. It provides direct code execution with debugging.

Yes, of course. And still I can't find the run option in this addon. And I'm not really into coding in vbs that much, so sublime text will be just enough for me.

It turns out that it's pretty straightforward. Did you see my posted answer?


Install the Sublime Text VBScript
package

Ensure VBScript is checked in the Tools Build System menu.

Press Ctrl+B or select Build from the Tools menu to run your script.


